# Trying to understand the "big picture" of Egorov's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I understand the specific mechanical steps of the proof, but I'm finding it difficult to see the general strategy. Firstly, this is the version of Egorov's theorem I refer to:

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions converging almost everywhere to $f$ on a set $E$, where $\mu(E) < \infty$. Then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ almost everywhereon $E$.

I have tried to write my prof's explanation out in a way that's more intuitive to me. Please let me know if I have the right idea, Suppose that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$ almost everywhere on $E$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $A \subset E$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in E - A$

Now, let $D = E - A$. The aim is that we for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ we can find $B \subset D$ with $\mu(B) < \epsilon$ such that $f$ converges uniformly on $D - B$.

To begin constructing this set, I define a set $D_{n,k}$.

$$D_{n,k} = \{x \in D : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{k}\}$$

and another set

$$B_{n,k} = \bigcup_{i=n}^\infty D_{n,k}$$

> Now given any $k_0$, if $x \in D - \bigcup_k B_{n,k}$ then  $|f_i(x) - f(x)| < 1/k_0$ for all $i \geq n$. Therefore $f$ is uniformly convergent on $D - \bigcup_k B_{n,k}$. My aim is to restrict this union to some subset $\bigcup_k B_{j,k}$ whose measure is arbitrarily small and where uniform continuity still holds.

Since there is no $x \in D_{n,k}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I have that

$$0 = \mu(\limsup_{n \to \infty} D_{n,k}) = \mu(\limsup_{n \to \infty} B_{n,k}) = \mu(\lim_{n \to \infty} B_{n,k})$$

This result lets me take a subsequence of $B_{n,k}$ where the measure of each member is arbitrarily small. In particular, if I take the each member $B_{j,k}$ such that the measure of each is less than $\epsilon / 2^{k+1}$, then I can define a set $B$ as the union of all these members, whose measure is less than $\epsilon$. Note that $B = \bigcup_k B_{j,k}$ where $\mu(B) < \epsilon$. It is also straightforward to verify that $f_n$ is uniformly continuous on $D - B = E - A - B$.

Finally, $\mu(A) = 0$ and $B$ can be constructed such that $\mu(B) < \epsilon$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$. Therefore $f_n$ is uniformly convergent almost everywhere on $E$.

Comment: Your statement of the theorem should say "converges uniformly" and not "converges absolutely."

Comment: What you are showing (and what Egorov's theorem claims) is that $f_n$ converges to $f$ "almost uniformly", in the sense that for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $B_\epsilon\subset E$ with $\mu(B_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ and $\lim_n\sup_{x\in E\setminus B_\epsilon}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$.

Comment: " Then f_n converges uniformly to f almost everywhere on E." That is false.

Comment: So $f_n$ converges uniformly on $E-B$ where the measure of $B$ is arbitrarily small does not imply that $f_n$ converges uniformly almost everywhere on $E$? I think I understand why, since $\epsilon$ is taken to be nonzero so $\mu(B)$ is always nonzero, no matter how small.

Comment: **Example:** $f_n(x)=x^n$ converges to $0$ at each $x\in[0,1)$, converges uniformly to $0$ on each interval $[0,1-\epsilon]$ ($0<\epsilon<1$) but does not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.